# Failing to compare php date with mysql date

Tags: php, mysql, date, comparison, string-comparison

Got stuck in a complex or maybe stupid problem. I am getting a query from mysql, and then trying to compare a date column with a PHP data which i formatted to the same format i.e "Y-m-d" it always results in no match, although i see there is a match.. and it gets the right result set too.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); // set timezone to our timezone
$constantTime = time(); // get value of time in constant
$appDate = date("Y-m-d", $constantTime); //that defines php time variable - 
$queryDate = "SELECT * FROM date WHERE date='$appDate'";
$resultDate = mysql_query($queryDate) or die("Sorry Website Under Maintainence");
$recordDate = mysql_fetch_array($resulDate);
if ($appDate == date("Y-m-d", strtotime($recordDate['date']))) {
    echo "MATCH    ";
    $dateID = $recordDate['dateID'];
} else {
    mysql_query("insert into date(date) values('$appDate')")or die("Database write error1");
    $resultDate = mysql_query($queryDate) or die("Sorry Website Under Maintainence");
    $recordDate = mysql_fetch_array($resultDate);
    echo "NO MATCH ";
    $dateID = $recordDate['dateID'];
}
```

This is always triggering the else, i tried === instead of ==, i tried strcmp

Comment: Why not do the date->string massaging in the SQL query with DATE_FORMAT?

Comment: the sql query is working fine, it gives result set. its just when i try to use the result set for comparison is a problem. so comparison after result is in php.

Comment: What are the values of `$appDate` and `date("Y-m-d",strtotime($recordDate['date']))`?

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 0):

As i assume you're comparing datetime field, you have two possibilities:

**Cast field to date:**

```
$queryDate = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE date(your_date_field) = date('$appDate')";
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

or

**Modify your date format to be ISO compatible:**

```
$appDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $constantTime); //it defines date in format 2015-03-14 15:00:00
$queryDate = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_date_field='$appDate'";
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507642/mysql-date-comparison-with-date-format)