# mysql how to compare date in the format dd-mon-yy

Tags: mysql, date, format, compare

How do I compare date in the format `dd-mon-yy`? For example: 10-NOV-14 > 07-OCT-13.

```
select expiration_date from grocery where expiration_date < 14-oct-13
```

Comment: What is the data type of the `expiration_date` column? The answer will vary depending on the data type.

Comment: You should be storing the dates in MySQL's default YYYY-MM-DD date format. It makes life *much* easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507642/mysql-date-comparison-with-date-format).

Comment: You should use MySQL's date format and not your own:
`SELECT expiration_date FROM grocery WHERE expiration_date < '2013-10-13';`

When using the date field, you can also do things like `WHERE expiration_date < now() - interval 1 month`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: it is in the format dd-mon-yy  for example  10-NOV-14

Comment: Yachee - when you do `desc grocery`, what data type shows for `expiration_date`? `DATE`? `DATETIME`? `TIMESTAMP`? `CHAR`? `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
select expiration_date from grocery
where expiration_date < STR_TO_DATE('14-oct-13', '%d-%b-%y')
```

`expiration_date` will also need to be wrapped in `STR_TO_DATE` if it is not already a `DATE` format.