# How to write a SQL

Tags: sql

How to write a SQL to select the TABLE_1 result 
which `(TABLE_1.NUMBER_1 > TABLE_2.NUMBER_2) and (TABLE_1.DATE_1 > TABLE_2.DATE_2)`

SQL result would be:

TABLES_1

```
NUMBER_1 , DATE_1
5          2015/4/1
```

Source Tables :

TABLE_1

```
NUMBER_1 , DATE_1
3          2015/3/1
4          2015/2/1
5          2015/4/1
6          2015/1/1
```

TABLE_2

```
NUMBER_2 , DATE_2
3          2015/2/1
3          2015/3/1
```

Comment: The answer is basically just a `JOIN` whose joining condition is exactly what you wrote in the first paragraph.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres, Oracle, DB2?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Exists` operator.

```
select * 
from TABLE_1 A
Where exists 
(
select 1 
from TABLE_2 B
Where A.NUMBER_1 > B.NUMBER_2 
and A.DATE_1 > B.DATE_2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on data types of date column, is it a date column or string column?

Look the below post that has useful information for date format.
[mysql date comparison with date_format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507642/mysql-date-comparison-with-date-format)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve your result. Here is a simple way using join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_1 JOIN TABLE_2 ON 
          (TABLE_1.NUMBER_1 > TABLE_2.NUMBER_2) AND 
          (TABLE_1.DATE_1 > TABLE_2.DATE_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will take those rows from table1 for values of which there are no rows in table2 breaking your condition:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
    (
      NUMBER_1 INT ,
      DATE_1 DATE
    )
DECLARE @table2 TABLE
    (
      NUMBER_2 INT ,
      DATE_2 DATE
    )

INSERT  INTO @table1
VALUES  ( 3, '20150301' ),
        ( 4, '20150201' ),
        ( 5, '20150401' ),
        ( 6, '20150101' )

INSERT  INTO @table2
VALUES  ( 3, '20150201' ),
        ( 3, '20150301' )


SELECT  *
FROM    @table1 t1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                     FROM   @table2 t2
                     WHERE  t2.NUMBER_2 >= t1.NUMBER_1
                            OR t2.DATE_2 >= t1.DATE_1 )
```

Output:

```
NUMBER_1    DATE_1
5           2015-04-01
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this version?

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.*
FROM TABLE_1 T1 
    INNER JOIN TABLE_2 T2 ON T1.NUMBER1 > T2.NUMBER2
        AND T1.DATE1 > T2.DATE2
```

Here is a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e465f/5) with how the code works on your sample data.