# MySQL Delete from ranged dates

Tags: mysql

Hello I'm trying to delete all data ranging from **04/15/2014** to **03/16/2016**. My problem is that the data type for the dates is `varchar`. The format is m/d/Y. My current sql code is here

```
DELETE FROM ending_inventory WHERE STR_TO_DATE(dater, '%m/%d/%Y')  BETWEEN '04/15/2014' AND '03/16/2016'
```

and it's not doing anything.

Is there a way to do this without changing the data type to `DATE`? Because I already have tons of data..

Comment: Try using DELETE FROM ending_inventory WHERE STR_TO_DATE(dater, '%Y/%m/%d')  BETWEEN '2014/04/15' AND '2016/03/16'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this. STR_TO_DATE FUNCTION change character into date and its default format is 'YYYY-mm-dd'

```
 DELETE FROM ending_inventory
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(dater, '%m/%d/%Y') 
 BETWEEN '2014-04-15' AND '2016-03-16';
```

[DATE FUNCTIONS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
Hope this will work for you.

Comment: The dates in the dater field is formatted as m/d/Y and I tried your code, it didn't work.

Comment: can you use str_to_date with '2014-04-15' AND '2016-03-16' both dates

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to say with that both dates?

Comment: dater is in varchar and dates there are formatted like m/d/Y

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a date to strings. You need to generate dates from the two strings you're trying to compare between. See Jon Skeets answer here: [mysql date comparison with date_format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507642/mysql-date-comparison-with-date-format)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to parse your date:

```
select date_format(str_to_date('12/31/2011', '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y%m');
```

Comment: I don't get your answer