# Get a column (id) from mysql table where created on column less than specific date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below columns in book_history table. Every new book taken will have entry in this table with a new auto increment id, current date, student id and book id.

```
Id, RecordCreatdOn, StudentId, BookId
```

I want to get students (studentId) who have last taken any book before '2017-12-31'. Can anyone help me with the query to fetch the same ?

Comment: From memory, that would be Alice, Bob, and Charlie.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I think this community is to help people, not to criticize from morning till night...

Answer (score 3):

You need to group by the student to get every students last book with `max(RecordCreatdOn)`

```
select studentId
from book_history
group by studentId
having max(RecordCreatdOn) < '2017-12-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

That is straight forward:

```
 Select Distinct StudentID from book_history where 
    RecordCreatedOn < @yourDate
```

Comment: This won't work - if a user checked out a book before and after `@yourDate` they would be returned by this

Comment: He need students who have took any book before a specific date. Didn't understand why it wouldn't work

Comment: This part `who have last taken any book before '2017-12-31'` implies they also haven't taken a book since then.  I missed it too at first, almost posted the same answer

Answer (score 0):

If you google 'mysql date comparisons', you'll get a LOT of Stackoverflow examples. Look at answers such as: [mysql date comparison with date_format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507642/mysql-date-comparison-with-date-format)

That can give you at least somewhere to start.

Try this query:

```
Select StudentId from book_history
WHERE DATE(RecordCreatdOn) <= '2017-12-31'
```